# How to handle homeschooling in another language?

Tags: language, homeschooling

I want to home-school my child (He is now 2 years old).

However I live in a country where homeschooling is not allowed (at least not in the country's school system). Also, educational materials for homeschooling are quite limited in my language.

There are some people who do it, but most of those I know are either foreign nationals or ethnic minorities who registered their children in their home country and use the mother tongue as a school language.

The option for me would be to use an English/US umbrella school, but that would mean to teach in English. And that would require my son to speak a reasonable English by the age of 6/7 and me/my wife having an excellent command of the language as well. (We can speak fluently, but we definitely cannot match a native speaker).

(We did not try to teach our son English yet)

I am looking for a similar experience, or, much better, some studies on how well this is/can be accomplished.

Comment: When you say "homeschooling is not allowed" in your contry, do you mean it is illegal according to your local laws? I'm guessing that your contry's laws require you to put your children in "official" schools then. If you circumvent that by registering them in another country, it sounds like you want to hide them from your local laws. That might be a dangerous road -- or I might have completely misunderstood you?

Comment: While not illegal, there is no legal framework to do it with the local curricula, to obtain a local diploma at the end. No way to sustain exams for homeschooled childen, no way to register your children as homeschooled. My solution may look like a legal workaround, but it is not illegal in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a requirement to put children in official schools? Will you do that, and homeschool in addition? I'm just being curious here because I want to understand your situation and your plan.

Comment: The legal requirement is to put children in a recognized school - either local or abroad. Having them registered with a US school will let me educate them at home (no need for additional local school). Transfers and diploma equivalency are done as for any foreign pupil moving to country (some paperwork, some tests, but nothing impossible).

Answer (score 2):

A search of several educational databases is not turning up any articles to directly address your question. As you note, most people using home-schooling internationally are expatriates, so searching sites focusing on expatriate home-schooling may yield some helpful [testimonials](http://www.k12.com/int/stories/what-people-say#.UWBhuVdkFZA).

Your best bet might be to initiate conversations with a few schools to find out how well they serve people in your situation. In particular, you might contact the [K12 International Academy](http://www.k12.com/int#.UWBx2FdkFZA) which has [global affiliations](http://www.k12.com/int/about-our-school/global-affiliations#.UWByGVdkFZA) in Asia, Africa, Europe, and South America. You might also look at the [Calvert School](http://homeschool.calvertschool.org/), which has been around since 1906, is internationally accredited, and claims students in 60 countries. Either of these schools could probably connect you with parents in a situation similar to yours.

Other homeschool options are discussed on this [expat website](http://www.expatinfodesk.com/expat-guide/moving-with-your-children/school-systems/home-schooling/).